# how to establish a db2 connection in matlab?

Tags: matlab, db2

how to establish a db2 connection in matlab? I have the following script running..

```
conn = database('db2','kshitiz','database','COM.ibm.db2os390.sqlj.jdbc.DB2SQLJDriver','jdbc:db2:sample');

ping(conn);
```

it gives me invalid connection.

Comment: I made an effort answering your question - you could at least comment on my answer (whether it helped or didn't)!

Answer (score 0):

Not much experience with database or ping, but from: [database on MathWorks Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/database/ug/database.html)

> `conn = database(instance,username,password,Name,Value)` 
>   connects to the database, instance, via JDBC driver with connection properties specified by one or more Name,Value pair arguments

and from [ping on MathWorks Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/database/ug/ping.html)

> In this example, the database connection conn has been terminated or is not successful.
>
> ```
> ping(conn)
> Cannot Ping the Database Connection
> ```

I don't know if there's much help anyone could give without knowing more specific information about your database. But I suspect that you've incorrectly used the `database` command - double check that your database name (it should be the first argument), your username and password (2nd and 3rd arguments) and your driver and url (4th and 5th arguments) are all correct.